# Making a tuple-like compile-time "linked-list" with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I was pondering possible implementations of `std::tuple` (and any similar template classes with a variable number of "members" defined at compile time), and I thought perhaps one could create a "recursive type" resembling a linked list. I tried compiling the following test-case:

```
template <typename FirstType, typename... OtherTypes>
class TupleLite
{
  public:
    FirstType type_;
    TupleLite<OtherTypes...> other_types_;
};

int main()
{
  TupleLite<int,double> mytuple;
}
```

The class itself compiles without error, but the instantiation throws the error `wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1 or more)`. I believe this is because `TupleLite<int, double>` tries to instantiate a `TupleLite<double>`, which tries to instantiate a `TupleLite<>`, for which there is no valid definition.

Can this "recursively sized class" be salvaged? I tried defining the "no-argument specialization" of `TupleLite` as follows:

```
template <>
class TupleLite {}
```

....but that doesn't seem to work, although `g++` and `clang++` seem to disagree on exactly why.

From `g++`, the most relevant errors seem to be:

```
error: template specifiers not specified in declaration of ‘template<class FirstType, class ... OtherTypes> class TupleLite’
  class TupleLite
        ^
error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1 or more)
 TupleLite<OtherTypes...> other_types_;
                          ^
```

`clang++`, however, says:

```
error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of class 'TupleLite'
template <>
^
error: redefinition of 'TupleLite' as different kind of symbol
class TupleLite
      ^
```

Comment: Have you heard of [`TypeList`](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html)?

Comment: @RSahu No, I hadn't.

Comment: ...But ``template <> class TupleLite {}`` is valid C++11?

Comment: @Cinch The errors I get with `g++` don't make much sense to me, but `clang++` says: `extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of class 'TupleLite'` and `redefinition of 'TupleLite' as different kind of symbol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary template definition of `TupleLite` specifies that it requires at least one template argument, `FirstType`. Since that isn't what you want to express, provide a primary template defition which ends up also handling the empty case like this:

```
template <typename...>
class TupleLite{};
```

And one partial specializations:

```
template <typename FirstType, typename... OtherTypes>
class TupleLite<FirstType, OtherTypes...>
{
  public:
    FirstType type_;
    TupleLite<OtherTypes...> other_types_;
};
```

[Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9783d48889bceaae).

EDIT : Thanks to Nikos for pointing out that the empty spec was not needed in this case.

Comment: You don't need the empty args specialization. Just define the base template : [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db65288a2503dfa8)

Comment: Ah, that makes quite a bit of sense. Thank you.